# Try to import JSON image from placeholder. Got errors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-json

I am new to Android kotlin and are currently making a app that import JSON from a url. I am trying to display a image with info like title etc.

This error (look futher down) appear in Logcat when I tried to import image from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos

Got a tips to set "User-Agent" as the header, the URLs will not work. But all effort have not worked.

Any help or tips is great.

Thanks

```
0   
albumId 1
id  1
title   "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt"
url "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952"
thumbnailUrl    "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
```

---

```
Logcat: 
2022-03-29 21:53:09.161 12423-12423/com.example.mvvmretrofit W/Glide: Load failed for https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796 with size [1036x550]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: 410)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: 410)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: 410)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
          Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: 410
```

MainAdapter.kt

```
class MainAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MainViewHolder>() {
    var movies = mutableListOf<Model.Movie>()
    fun setMovieList(movies: List<Model.Movie>) {
        this.movies = movies.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = AdapterMovieBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return MainViewHolder(binding)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val movie = movies[position]
        holder.binding.name.text = movie.albumId.toString()
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(movie.thumbnailUrl).into(holder.binding.imageview)

    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }
}
class MainViewHolder(val binding: AdapterMovieBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
}
```

RetrofitService.kt

```
   @GET("/albums/1/photos")
    @Headers("User-Agent: android")
    fun getAllMovies() : Call<List<Model.Movie>>


    companion object {
        var retrofitService: RetrofitService? = null

        fun getInstance() : RetrofitService {
            if (retrofitService == null) {
                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()

                retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService::class.java)
            }
            return retrofitService!!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check if your emulator/phone has the Internet connection?

Comment: Yes. I get the albumId, but the image won't load.